# Heyzap Unity SDK - whats the best approach to preload or cache ads with different tagID before calling show()

Tags: heyzap

I am working on a Unity game that needs to be monetized with Heyzap SDK. I integrated the latest SDK that had some issues earlier and its fixed.
Now I want to know whats the best possible way to preload or cache interstitial and reward ads before calling `Show` method.

In doc, it says, `Fetch` right after initializing Heyzap SDK.

What if I have 3 different placements in game ? ie, three different tagID's.
I know that I can make use of `HZInterstitialAd.Fetch("tagID1")` and so on...

I just want to know that I am doing it in the right way....

So these are my questions.....

1) I am calling `HeyzapAds.Start("xxxxxxx")` in `Awake()` of one of my cs scripts. Is `Awake()` the right function to initialize Heyzap SDK ?

2) Can I call `Fetch` method subsequently like below. Because I want all these 3 ads with different tagids to be preloaded or cached. Will it cause any network bottleneck because of the subsequent web service calls ? Is it safe to load Ads like this ?

```
HZInterstitialAd.Fetch(tag1)
HZInterstitialAd.Fetch(tag2)
HZInterstitialAd.Fetch(tag3)
```

3) In my game, as soon as the user launch the app or when user hard close ( remove from memory ) and launch the app again, I have to show an Ad ( bootup ad ). To achieve this, I used the below code, but it's not working. Could you let me know how to show bootup Ad or show an AD right after initializing Heyzap SDK.
Is there any delegate available to check if the SDK initialized before I attempt to call `Show` method or Should I rely on `Fetch` and its respective `interstitial` or `incentivized` delegates ?.

```
HZInterstitialAd.Fetch(tag1)
HZInterstitialAd.Fetch(tag2)
HZInterstitialAd.Fetch(tag3)
HZInterstitialAd.ShowWithOptions(option);
```

I also tried calling from Android's Activity's `Resume` and `Start` to Unity's function that trigger Heyzap `interstitial` Ad. But its not working either.

Note: If I attempt to call `Show` after a small pause say 1 or 2 seconds, all calls are working. It seems that calling `Show` right after initialization is not working. It needs some time to search and `Fetch` Ads from available networks ?. So whats the recommended approach to show **BOOTUP Ad** ?

Comment: any updates on this ?